Есть ли аналог RemoteObjectManager в 3-ей версии API
В версии 2.1 api есть класс RemoteObjectManager, самостоятельно запрашивающий данные при перемещении карты, есть ли его аналог в третьей версии api?

"если ли" что ?

Аналога ObjectManager в JS API 3.0 нет, также отсутствуют LoadingObjectManager и RemoteObjectManager. Версия API 3.0 находится в процессе разработки, и мы стараемся работать над новыми возможностями, но планов добавлять аналог пока нет.
